# Scala can't deal with huge objects?

Tags: scala

I have a syntactically correct Scala source file holding a huge data structure. The code looks like this:

```
object ChiSquareAlpha
{
  val ChiSquareToAlphaIndexTable = Map(
    1 -> Array(0.00016,0.00063,0.00393,0.01579,0.06418,0.14847,0.45494,1.07419,1.64237,2.70554,3.84146,5.41189,6.63490,10.82757),
    .. 9998 other entries ..
    10000 -> Array(9673.95,9711.71,9768.53,9819.19,9880.79,9925.36,9999.33,10073.68,10118.82,10181.66,10233.75,10292.58,10331.93,10442.73)
  )
}
```

So you can see, the object holds a huge lookup table, a Map[Int, Array[Double]]  with 10000 entries.
Compilation takes about a minute, but finishes without warnings or errors. 
But at runtime it fails with:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid this class index 4280 in constant pool in class file bm/statistic/ChiSquareAlpha$
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.scala$tools$nsc$util$ScalaClassLoader$$super$findClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.findClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:44)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.findClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.scala$tools$nsc$util$ScalaClassLoader$$super$loadClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.loadClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:50)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.loadClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at bm.statistic.ChiSquareTest.testOfIndependence(ChiSquareTest.scala:323)
at ...
```

I tested this with scala 2.9.2 and scala 2.10. Same result.
When the object is much smaller - let's say 500 map entries - the program works.
So I guess scala is unable to deal with such big files.
Any solution proposals?

Comment: The quick solution is to read those values from file.

Comment: +1 on om-nom-nom's comment. Bulk data *never* belongs in source code!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct, your syntax looks fine.

I apologize for the disappointing answer, this is [an open bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6543) with Scala:

> Scala Programming Language SI-6543
>   scala compile fails on simple but lengthy repetitive script (ClassNotFound and/or StackOverflowError)

It's fix priority is Major (which is high) and you can [find more information about it](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6543) (they explain *why* it happens).

You can keep track of the progress. Meanwhile, you can create that information in a flat file and read the data from it as a temporary fix.

Comment: It doesn't look like the same error to me at all. The error of the question is related to a class file format.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6543?focusedCommentId=60494&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-60494

Comment: It's a related bug. See comment from Phil Walker 19/Oct/12 7:13 PM in the bug report. this is about a slightly different java.lang.ClassFormatError with a big object. I think the detailed error message depends on the code. 
The bug report hint convinced me, to see that's a Scala bug.

Comment: @BitMagier Note that the bug report contains an example of a file that causes `ClassFormatError` as well as an attached file with such. I think that you should comment on that bug report and mention you're having the same issue (add an input file). I'm sure it's help

Comment: I agree with @DanielC.Sobral, these bugs aren't related at all. It was the reporter (the one also responsible for the comment) that didn't realize that.

Comment: And I speculate if the problem isn't related to bytecode size limitations imposed by the JVM.

Comment: @pedrofurla So you think that this bug report contains two different bugs, one of which (which is reliably recreatable with the attached file) is the same one that OP is having and the other is not? I guess that makes sense. I'm having no problems reproducing the bug OP is having (and the bug the guy is having in the lower comment).

Comment: Exactly, but I say more, the appended bug (the 2nd one) is the one reported by @BitMagier. I think it's not really a bug, just a JVM limitation.

Comment: Don't know why, but I can't reproduce the ClassFormatError I posted yesterday. Scala 2.9.2 compiler doesn't return after 25 minues. With Scala 2.10 I get a NoClassDefFoundError as in https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6543. I added my issue.